# Update multiple tables simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a number of tables in an SQL, the contents have a key called "hashtag_id" which contains a number (in this case 1-5).  I want to quickly go in and change all the items with the id "1" to "5".

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Essentially I need to change ALL tables with a value of 1 to have a value of 5. There are several hundred of these tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each table you need to run the following query:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET hashtag_id = 5
WHERE hashtag_id = 1
```

This finds all the rows where `hashtag_id` is 1 and sets it to 5.

---

To get the names of all the tables you can run the following query:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
AND column_name = 'hashtag_id'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update table set hashtag_id = 5
where hashtag_id = 1;
```

if you have multiple tables, you can do something like that in phpmyadmin (or any mysql management tool)

this will query the [information_schema.columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) table (describing all your table and columns), and write an update query for every column named `hashtag_id`)

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ', 
               table_name, 
               ' SET ',
               column_name,
               ' = 5 WHERE ',
               column_name,
               ' = 1;' 
             )
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'hashtag_id';
--maybe add  AND table_schema = <your_schema>
```

copy and execute the result

This could probably also be done in a stored procedure using dynamic sql (not used to in MySQL, so no example).

Comment: In a live system, be sure to execute your query within one transaction to avoid unwanted inconsistencies. Could be that the second answer would be treated as a single transaction but I'd be careful in a live system and handle the transaction explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET hashtag_id=5
WHERE hashtag_id=1;
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.